# React Native: Can you force refreshing the App or rerendering the page onPress of a button?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have an app with SignInPage component and Main App component.

If the user is signed in, the App will render MainApp. Otherwise, SignInPage will be rendered.

On press of Sign In button from SignInPage, I would like to refresh or re render the page so that it redirects to the MainApp component.

Are there any ways to do this ? Or any workaround for such routing ?

Comment: I was asking specifically for React Native App. I have all the logics set up for saving current user id when signed in and checking signed in or not. My question is, are there any way to redirect to the main app component from login page upon the press of successful sign in button? Forcing refreshing will do, but not sure how to implement it. Anybody know how? Are there any example apps built with React Native similar to this?

Comment: you need to use a navigator or navigatoriOS component and use push to a next route or replace the existing route (with the same page) to get a reload effect  http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

Comment: Is it possible to do it like location.reload() in web dev without using navigator or navigatorIOS?

Comment: without using a navigator, you may force a render by changing states. so if you have a value of a text component set to this.state.textvalue then by calling this.setState({ textvalue: 'asdf' }); you should be triggering shouldComponentUpdate. review react lifecycle

Comment: @boredgames Thank you that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

So there's two ways that I can think of doing this. One would be to have the app always try to load the sign-in page at the start of the app. Then in the `sign-in` component, do something like:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  if (currentUserStore.getUser()) {
    return this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Home',
      component: MainApp
    });
  }
}
```

So what this does is check to see if you have a user logged in. If you do, then it navigates to the MainApp scene, otherwise it does nothing and renders the `sign-in` normally.

Another way to do it is using state. So you can make a `Home` component like:

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loggedIn: false
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    if (currentUserStore.getUser()) {
      return this.setState({
        loggedIn: true
      });
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    if this.state.loggedIn
      <MainApp ... />
    else
      <SignIn ... />
  }
});
```

Then in your SignIn part of the component, make sure to `setState` to true when the user logs in successfully.